# How can I make ColAR Mix?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to do colAR mix Augmented Reality in Unity using the Vuforia plugin. 
I'm trying to changes the material of the 3d model based on the colors of image target.
I don't know how can i get cropped image target from camera for change material.
Thanks so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. This is NOT your ordinary Q&A site.